# Check if data contains a value from List of string in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ.  I just want to ask if it is possible to check if a field contains a value from a list of string.  Say I have a list of string as defined below.

```
 List<String> yearList = new List<string>();

 yearList.Add("2012");
 yearList.Add("2015");
```

I also have a class `Member`:

```
class Member
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Object `data` is of a class that implements `IEnumerable<Member>`:

```
IEnumerable<Member> data = ...
```

So data may be a `List<Member>` or a `Member[]`, or anything else that represents an enumerable sequence of Member objects.

Now I want to get the data if the `year` field is in my list of years `yearList`.

Or to be more precise:

**Requirement**: Given an object data, that implements `IEnumerable<Member>`, and given an object `yearList`, which implements `IEnumerable<string>`, where the string is a textual representation of a year, give me all Members in object `data` that have a value of property `Year` that has a textual representation that equals at least one of the values in `yearList`.

For example `data` is as follows:

```
Name (string) | Year (int)
    Ralph     |   2012
    Rafael    |   2012
    Bea       |   2014
    Lee       |   2015
```

and `yearList` is the sequence of strings {"2012", "2015"}. I am expecting a result like

```
Name (string) | Year (int)
    Ralph     |   2012
    Rafael    |   2012
    Bea       |   2014
    Lee       |   2015
```

I tried the following, but that didn't work

```
 data.where(x => x.year.contains(yearList));   <--- THIS CODE NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
```

Is that possible in LINQ?

Comment: `data.where(x => yearList.Any(y => y == x.year));` that will do it; other ways as well, if not, explain in other details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: or `data.where(x => yearList.Contains(x.year));`

Comment: @JochemVanHespen in this case yes, but `Contains` could be an issue. To be honest, the lists should be an `List<int>` and the property an `int` as well and then compared.  Anyways, if this was other than year's, I would have used the overloaded [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_Char_System_StringComparison_) and used the StringComparison.

Answer (score 1):

Think how you would do it with loops

You might do:

```
foreach(var d in data){
    if(yearList.Contains(d.year))
        ...
}
```

But this is different to what you wrote; what you wrote doesn't really make sense:

```
//data.where(x => x.year.contains(yearList));

//as a loop
foreach(var d in data){
    if(d.year.Contains(yearList))
        ...
}
```

"If a single year contains a list of years..."

---

So, then you're working with things like LINQ Where and Select, think of them as like a loop operating over the list of things, and you provide a mini-method that accepts a single parameter, of whatever is in the collection, and returns something else. LINQ will loop over the collection calling your method once per item, passing in the item. You get to choose what the item is called

This is why it helps to have plural names for collections and singular names as the argument in the mini-method (lambda).

```
var cars = //list of cars

cars.Where(car => car.Maker == "Ford");
```

Avoid using bland names like `x`, because it *doesn't help you keep straight, in your head, what things are. Take a look at this:

```
var cars = //list of cars
var seekingMakers = new []{"Ford", GM"};

cars.Where(car => seekingMakers.Any(seekingMaker => car.Maker == seekingMaker));
```

We've named the outer (`car`) and the inner (`seekingMaker`) to help keep them apart and remind us what they are. `seekingMaker` is a single *string* in an string array `seekingMakers`.

---

So, for your `Where` you have to return a boolean from your lambda, and that is used to determine whether the item in the list makes it into the output or not

```
var winners = //your list of people/year

winners.Where(winner => yearList.Contains(winner.Year));
```

You can't say `winner.Year.Contains(yearList)` - you could say `winner.Year.IsContainedWithin(yearList)` - but there's no such thing as `IsContainedWithin` - it's the other way round: `collection.Contains(singular)` - not "singular contains collection"

---

Now, you never said what datatype "Year" was in your list of people - maybe it's a string, in which case it makes sense why you'd have `yearList` as a string.. but if it's *not* a string, then I strongly recommend you avoid having it be a different data type, because converting it in place will clutter up your LINQ statement, and also lower performance, because C# will spend a large amount of time converting values over and over again

At any time you want to run a search against some fixed value, match the datatype of the value to the data type of the data being searched:

Do this:

```
var winners = //your list of people/year with INTEGER years
var years = new[]{ 2012, 2015 };

winners.Where(winner => yearList.Contains(winner.Year));
```

Not these:

```
var winners = //your list of people/year with INTEGER years
var years = new[]{ "2012", "2015" };

//don't convert the winner's Year
winners.Where(winner => yearList.Contains(winner.Year.ToString()));

//really don't parse the string years to ints over and over
winners.Where(winner => yearList.Select(stringYear => int.Parse(stringYear)).Contains(winner.Year));
```

If your data is coming to you as strings, convert it once:

```
var winners = //your list of people/year with INTEGER years

//pass every item to int.Parse and capture the result to an array you can reuse
var years = stringYearsFromElsewhere.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

winners.Where(winner => yearList.Contains(winner.Year));
```

---

Particularly when working with LINQ, strive to find ways to make the code read like a book..